# phpmailer multiple addAddress Could not instantiate mail function

Tags: phpmailer, iis-8, windows-server-2012, php-5.6

I've been using phpmailer for some time and I've noticed now that all my additional `to` address entries (additional `$mail->addAddress` or `$mail->addCC` or `$mail->addBCC`) cause the page to return:

```
Could not instantiate mail function.
```

The page works fine with only one address. I'm using it on Windows 2012 server. I've found some references to those functions not working on Win32, but they used to work. Any ideas?

```
                require 'autoload.php';
            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            $mail = new PHPMailer;
            $mail -> CharSet = "UTF-8";
            $firstname=$_GET['firstname'];
            $lastname=$_GET['lastname'];
            $email=$_GET['email'];
            $phone=$_GET['phone'];
            $mail->setFrom('news@imj.org.il', 'News');
            $mail->addReplyTo('news@imj.org.il', 'News');
            $mail->addAddress('webmaster@imj.org.il', 'Webmaster');
            $mail->addAddress('news@imj.org.il', 'News'); /****This doesn't work****/
            $mail->addBCC('news@gmail.com');/****This doesn't work****/
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Subject = "Friends Registration";
            $mail->Body = "First Name: ".$firstname . "<br>\r\n "; 
            $mail->Body .= "Last Name: ".$lastname . "<br>\r\n "; 
            $mail->Body .= "Email: " . $email . "<br>\r\n "; 
            $mail->Body .= "Tel: " . $phone . "<br>\r\n "; 
            $mail->AltBody = $firstname." " .$lastname." " . $email;
            if(!$mail->send()) 
            {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } 
            else 
            {
                echo "Message has been sent successfully";
            }
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your code. Also try sending via SMTP to localhost and show the output with `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2`.

Comment: SMTP doesn't work. I haven't been able to deploy it. I think it has to do with our organization's network (Exchange)

Comment: Exchange still uses SMTP, and the `mail()` function calls a local `sendmail` binary which opens an SMTP connection to localhost. If you don't have a local mail sever installed, neither will work. Otherwise you need to configure sending through the IP of your Exchange server instead. We can't guess your local config - you need to tell us.

Comment: This is from my php.ini[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = imj-org-il.mail.protection.outlook.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com
sendmail_from = news@imj.org.il

Comment: Like I said, the mail() function works and phpmailer works but with only one address.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the problem is with the mail server, which also doesn't send multiple email addresses, so I guess it doesn't have to do with phpMailer. Here is the log when I try to send a multiple address mail:

> PHP Warning:  mail(): SMTP server response: 550 5.7.64 TenantAttribution; Relay Access Denied [DB5EUR03FT036.eop-EUR03.prod.protection.outlook.com] in E:\site\temp\simplemail.php on line 14

Comment: That means that it can't figure out who you are, or you don't have permission to send to domains that are not your own. Does it work if you send to two addresses in your own domain?

Comment: Yes it does. It doesn't send outside of our domain. I guess if I want to try and change that I need to get help from our organization's IT department. Thanks for your input.